# plugin cordova-pdf-generator ionic

Tags: ionic, ionic3, ionic2

Utilizo o plugin c no ionic para gerar um arquivo do tipo pdf, porém se reparar no exemplo abaixo a escrita é html. Será que que tem uma forma de ao invés eu gerar o pdf gerar um arquivo html?

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
 
declare var cordova:any;    //global;
 
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
 
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
      const before = Date.now();
 
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
                console.log('DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER', (Date.now() - before), 'ms');
 
                //generate the pdf.
                cordova.plugins.pdf.fromData( '<html> <h1>  Hello World  </h1> </html>', options )
                .then(()=>'ok')
                .catch((err)=>console.err(err))
  }
 
}
```

Comment: alguém sabe se esse plugin ao transformar o html em pdf tem limite de tamanho do arquivo passado como html?